# The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

while saving the item in list "**The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again**" error. NLB is configured, for SQL we have seperate server.

i have done the following but no luck.
1) IISRESR in App server and NLB servers .
2)Restart All servers including SQL server.
3)Enabled anonymous authentication in all IIS.
4)Sharepoint search host controller restart. 
5) search host controller restart. in Central admin also .

No Luck. But i can upload a document in document library.

can any 1 help?? 
:(

Comment: This question will have better chance of getting solved on [SharePoint Stackexchange site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com). Stack overflow is targetting specific coding issues. Your question is more an infrastructure question, and very specific on SharePoint.

Comment: Check  [The server was unable to save the form at this time. Please try again.](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/02/the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

We had faced same issue and tried all five step but no luck. After that we restarted the server and issue fixed. In-spite of this if issue not fixed then rebuilt your system. if you have got any answer then let us know.

Thank you
Lovkesh Patel

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that this has been solved in SharePoint StackExchange site. But in case somebody gets directed to this page via search engine:

Occassionaly this happens because Anonymous Authentication is disabled in IIS Manager and Enabling the Anonymous Authentication solves this issue.

Please go to the web application in IIS Manager and enable Anonymous Authentication.

The other day I was having this issue and after fixing it, created a blog post [Here](https://rakibism.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/sharepoint-2013-adding-list-item-returns-error-the-server-was-unable-to-save-the-form-at-this-time-please-try-again/)

Hope this helps to other people having the same issue.